# c++ overload ambiguity between int64 and time_t

Tags: c++, public

I have a class Format that needs to compile for both 32 and 64 bit linux platforms.

The class has methods for adding primitive values, and then format the values according to a format string. More or less an encapsulation of `printf(...)`

My class looks like this:

```
class Format
{
public:
    Format(string fmt);
    add(int16_t x);
    add(int32_t x);
    add(int64_t x);
    add(time_t x);
}
```

When I compile for 32 bit the code compiles because int64_t and time_t translates to different types.
If I compile for 64 bit I get:

> error: ‘Format::add(time_t)’ cannot be overloaded

If I remove `add(time_t x)` I get a compile error from the 32 bit compiler:

> error: call of overloaded ‘add(time_t&)’ is ambiguous

I understand the reasons why the compilation fails.

But I fail to see the best solution for this problem?

I would like to not have to cast from time_t to int64_t at the caller.

So how can I implement this the best way for multi platform support?

I have a similar problem when adding "long" and "int" overload versions of add(...).

Regards
Klaus

Comment: Why do you have the same function with the same name, but taking arguments of conceptually very different types? In other words: you could just name the functions differently.

Comment: What do your functions do? Maybe name the functions dealing with time something else? It's difficult for me to imagine a case where I'd use the same name for something time related and everything else.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Wouldn't help sadly. If `time_t` is the same type as one of the other three types, the compiler will still not be able to distinguish the templates.

Comment: Take a `std::chrono::time_point` instead?

Comment: To reiterate, can you explain your use case? It is hard to imagine why you would need to do this.

Comment: I edited the original question to reflect the actual usecase.

Comment: In cases where the `time_t` and the matching integral value are equal value, is the output the same or different?

Comment: You should also note that it could *not* be an integral type. In [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) "**Arithmetic** type capable of representing times. Although not defined, this is **almost always** an integral value", while in [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t) "Arithmetic (until C11) Real (since C11) type capable of representing times."

Comment: @peter In cases where time_t and matching intergal values are the same then the output will be the same.

Comment: @KlausHolstJacobsen - then the solution is to overload only for the largest integral type you intend to pass (`long long` or `int64_t` as appropriate).   Implicit conversions mean that will work for all sized integral types.    At most, you might need an overload for `signed` and `unsigned` types.

Comment: @Peter For 32bit no intXX_t type maps to a long....so that requires me to implement `add(long i)` if I wish to be able to add a long, but on 64bit that is a duplicate for int64_t. Only way out as I see it is the greasy `#ifdef __wordsize 32`path...and I would prefer not to go down that path.

Answer (score 0):

`time_t` is more often than not either a signed 32 bit or a signed 64 bit integral type. (Its actual type is not guaranteed by the C++ standard).

If you are on a platform where it's a `typedef` to the same fundamental type as one of the fixed width integral types, then the compiler will not be able do distinguish your functions.

The best workaround is to take a leaf out of a C programmer's book and use

```
someMethod_time_t(time_t x)
```

and so on.

Comment: With all due respect, holy smokes that's ugly.

Comment: @PasserBy: Too bad. Because the type of `time_t` can be anything, you can't really use it with a set of overloaded functions. In that respect you're back to the good old C days.